# How can I put a div in the foreground with css?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have implemented the following website: [link](http://cihadkirhan.com/mytrans/index.php)

There are two textfields in the header part of the website. If you click on a textfield, a calender pops up. My problem is that the calender is not shown on the foreground although I set the css properties `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 999;`. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: This question is useless right now. No code and link not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following to your css

```
.row-3 {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `overflow:hidden;` from here `#header .row-3`

```
#header .row-3 {
    background: url("images/header-tail.gif") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
    height: 276px;
}
```

see the attached image how i did

[image]